# GIT : do a correct rebase

Tags: git

This is my current GIT state :

```
0
|\
| \
|  \
|   \
|    1
|    |\
|    | \
|    |  \
|    |   \
|    1    2
|   /     |
|  /      |
| /       |
0         |
|         |
|         |
|         |
```

The branch `0` is master

The branch `1` is a new feature that has been reviewed, then modified, then merged.

The branch `2` is starting from the branch `1` **before** it has been reviewed : this means it has the feature, but it is lacking some modifications.

### Issue

I would like to incorporate the changes that have been made & merged into my branch `2`.

What is the correct command to run, and on which branch ?

**EDIT** the file that is creating a conflict :

old state :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export const mockedData ...
```

new state :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';

export const mockedData ...
```

Comment: Why don't you merge `0` into `2`?

Comment: Because if I do so, it will generate a merge commit, and I don't want that. Is it possible to not do that ?

Comment: You want to get changes from `0` (after all merges) to `2`?

Comment: Exactly. The modifications are very minimal, like spelling mistakes.

Comment: Why are you adverse to merge commits?

Comment: If adverse == against, then because it pollutes my commit logs with unnecessary merge commits, while rebasing doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git checkout branch_2
git rebase branch_0
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives me a conflict about a file where I added a word : I don't know why, but the file is deleted in my `git status`. Shouldn't it be just "modified" ?

Comment: @trichetriche You should resolve the conflict, and then `git rebase --continue`, and you'll be fine. I'm not sure what's the state of your files, maybe if you provide more information I can better help you.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, resolving the conflict actually deletes my file ... I have updated my question with the states of the file, is that enough ?

Comment: Oh it was coming from a windows permission, git deleted the file but it wasn't able to recreate it ! Thank you for your help, I'll manage the permission issue on my own !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to incorporate chenges from branch-0 to branch-2, you shlould:

1 - checkout to the **branch-0**

```
git checkout 0
```

2 - rebase that branch to the **branch-2**

```
git rebase 2
```

3 - solve your conflicts and stage your changes

```
git add *
```

4 - continue your rebase

```
git rebase --continue
```